# Changing cell background and foreground color with different conditional formatting rules

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

I'm coloring the **background** of my sheet's rows with some arbitrary formula in conditional formatting for visual purpose — for example, striped with `=ISEVEN(ROW())`, or based on the text contents of a particular column, `=$B1="Groceries"`.

But now I also want some cells in the list to have custom **foreground, text** color according to **another, unrelated** formula. For example, red if it starts with `+`, red/green if it's above/below zero, blue for a substring match, etc.

Problem is, each rule tries to format both background and foreground color of a cell, and one rule always precedes the other. The lower rule makes the background light green, then the higher rule makes the text red... and even though I didn't instruct the higher rule to affect background (it's the default white), it still overrides the lower rule's background. So now it's red text on white background — the lower rule is totally ignored.

I could manually create "permutations" of each of the possible combinations: for example, light green background and red text if `=AND($B1="Groceries",C1>0)`, light green background and green text if `=AND($B1="Groceries",C1<0)`, light blue background and red text if `=AND($B1="Laundromat",C1>0)` and on and on... but this gets unruly and very tedious, especially if I have a lot of possibilities for both foreground *and* background.

Is there any way to instruct a conditional formatting rule to format only background or foreground?

Comment: As of a year ago, this is still not possible generally without additional formatting rules to take into account the overlapping rules, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73014269/google-sheets-overlapping-conditional-formatting). Using the alternating colors is the only real alternative here.

Answer (score 1):

From my research, it does not appear possible to do what you are requesting through the Google Sheets UI.  However, if you are willing to use the REST api and google sheets developer, you may be able to do this.  There is more information here:

https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/samples/conditional-formatting

Basically you still create the conditional rules but it looks like you have more granularity to change independent items rather than all or nothing.  For example, there is a recipe to only change the foreground and make a value italics without touching the background.
https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/samples/conditional-formatting#date-text

There is also another rule to only change the background to apply a color gradient without modifying the text color.
https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/samples/conditional-formatting#color-gradient

Your question doesn't specify programming language or client (other than using the UI settings).  Are you using the UI because you didn't know about the API options or is the UI required (ie not willing to try the REST API)?

Comment: These possibilities are awesome. The original question (as well as my edit) both assume using only the UI, but if it's possible with the REST API, then that would be as satisfying a conclusion as any. A full tutorial on the REST API is outside the scope of this question and the examples on Google's page are clear and concise, but could you include a link to "starter" information on basic use of the REST API? I expect the average joe who could use your answer will be comfortable working with code & learning, but probably won't have much experience with Google Sheet's API, so a link would help.

Comment: @Nebula  It seems that unless you have a google workspace account, you have to create a public app.  There is more info here:  https://developers.google.com/workspace/guides/get-started  I don't have a google workspace account myself so the proecess to do what  you are requesting is much more complicated.  I don't think it is as easy to do for a single spreadsheet as you are requesting.  I think the api is more for creating a general app that can be used by anyone who downloads your app for any project.  I am sorry I can't be more helpful.

Answer (score -1):

When you create conditional formatting rules, you can include a fill colour (or not), font colour/style (or not), and much else, for any cells where the condition(s) is met.

So, for your `=ISEVEN(ROW())` simply don't include any font colour option in its rule, similarly in your `contains +` rule, simply don't include any fill settings in its rule

Comment: Hello, could you elaborate? I'm using google drive's UI-based settings, and it always include all formatting in the rule. I would guess you mean there's someway to do this using code only?

Comment: Sorry, I'm answering based on Excel, I have no experience with google docs

Comment: Oh I see. I'm sorry for making misleading question with the Excel tag.

Answer (score -1):

I would make an attempt at using a custom formula (within the conditional formatting drop box options) that changes the font colour based on the "+" being present in the cell.

I would use a custom formula such as:

```
=RegExMatch(A1, "\+")
```

And then format the conditional formatting to suit your text colour choice.

This should search the cells in the defined column for the "+" and then reassign your desired font colour if the "+" expression is within the cell.

NOTE: The A1 (range) dictates the column that is being scanned and will likely have to be adjusted to suit your need.

ALSO NOTE: The "\" before the "+" symbol is there to signify that the plus symbol is a "special character".

[Examples of Regular Expressions](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1371417?hl=en)