# Non-Competing Conditional Formatting rules in Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

I have a spreadsheet with prospective team staff for my town's Little League. In it I have two Conditional format rules, each using a custom formula that covers the same range. One rule sets the whole row to **bold** if the person signed up to be a head coach and the other sets the background color to a certain color, depending on the division, e.g. "Tee Ball". The problem is that only one rule (whichever is listed first) renders...is there an option to have them both render since they don't conflict with one another? Or do I need to consolidate? I'd rather not go that route since the "head coach" rule only needs to be there once, but I'll have to incorporate that into each of the division rules + another (nearly identical) set for the rows division rows where people did not sign up to be assistant coach.

I probably don't need to list the formulas, but for the sake of completeness, here they are:

````
Range: A2:J41
Custom formula: =$B2="Tee Ball"
Style: make the row's background color red

**Rule 2**
Range: A2:J41
Custom formula: =$D2="Head Coach"
Style: set the whole row to be bold```

Thanks!
````

Comment: Hi It will be really helpful if you can provide a sample spreadsheet with dummy data including input and desired output.

Comment: I just realized that they do conflict with one another. My first rule sets the Bold, but the next rule doesn't have the Bold set, so it effectively gets undone. Looks like I need to load up on the rules

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Google Sheets Overlapping Conditional Formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73014269/google-sheets-overlapping-conditional-formatting)