# Is there a way to conditionally change the background and text color for a cell in Excel/Google Sheets without using many unique conditional rules?

Tags: excel, google-sheets, conditional-formatting

I'm currently creating a spreadsheet for a card collection, and I want the rows to have their background changed based on what element the card is, I also want the text color to change based on its rarity. I've so far changed the background of the row with a conditional formatting rule (=$I2="Element") for each element, but when I add another condition to change the text color based on rarity for the same cells, only one of the two can be applied at once.

Idealy I'd like to have the Element types and Rarities in a table which have an associated background/text color associated with them, and look at that table when I apply the formatting, but I don't know if that's possible, or how to do it if it is. Currently making a rule for every combination would need me to make 40 conditional formatting rules, and wouldn't easily let me change colors/add new elements. I'd rather avoid that if possible. I'm currently using Google Sheets, but I do have access to Excel if this would only be possible there. Thanks!

Comment: Having one condition change the colour of the cell and another change the colour of the text works fine for me in Excel 2016

Comment: possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73014269/google-sheets-overlapping-conditional-formatting

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to emulate VLOOKUP functionality to dynamically set the background color and text color of a cell (or row) based on a table of element names and rarity values with specified colors that you maintain separately (eg stored on a different sheet)?

If so, there's a [good tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tp50JMxCPSs) on how to achieve this with apps script.

[Here's a sample spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16EWRNRPEDcnP0tEsMC93SfWhsCU_mlXLROWCrPujO2U/edit?usp=sharing) I created based on that lesson that (I think) shows the full solution, and includes the app script.

1. Copy the sheet and you'll see a Color Testing custom menu at the top. You'll need to allow permissions the first time you click on items in this menu.

**HOW IT WORKS**

2. You'll see an **Elements** sheet, and a **ColorTable** sheet.
3. Edit the values in column C (bgColor) of the **ColorTable** sheet to assign a color name or hex code to each element. This assigns a background color for the corresponding element's cell on the Elements sheet. I did the first 15 or so, you can change as you like. You don't have to add any more to start testing (see step 5).
4. Edit the values in columns E & F (Rarity,textColor) of the **ColorTable** sheet to assign a rarity name and its associated color/hex code. This assigns a text color for any element's cell on the Elements sheet that has the matching Rarity value. Again, I started with 3 or 4 rarity values and associated text colors, you can edit/add as many as you like, but can test with just what's there.
5. From the custom Color Testing menu, select 'Set All Colors'. The cells in column B of the Elements sheet will be updated to reflect the assigned background and text colors.
6. Select 'Clear All Colors' to remove the formatting.

Go to Extensions->Apps Script to check out the code powering the solution.

Hopefully that's enough to get you started. Let me know if you run into any issues.